# New Task Form Field on Reassignment form for Approval Task Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, approval-process

Creating an approval task workflow.
Need to have another field added in the reassignment form view to allow the user to select an item from a drop down menu. 
I am able to display the new field in the form view but I am not able to retrieve the value.
I used the New Task Form Fields section from the Designer section.
I am fairly new to Sharepoint overall. 
I am using Sharepoint Designer 2010 and InfoPath 2010.

Comment: Check the column of task field. It will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field filed is kind of a task form field . If you want get these fields value follow this:

```
   Click on workflow to edit the task process.

   Click on Change the behavior of a single task .

   Define a workflow variable .

   Add a Set workflow variable in "When a task completes" section .

   Click on value and select "Current task:Approve(1)" as data source .

   Is field from source drop downlist you can see all the task form fields .

   Choose your field and click OK .
```

For more details check :

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/collect-data-from-a-user-in-a-workflow-HA010209808.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/80d3c5f8-4c25-438e-8a0a-324b47342383/how-to-get-approval-comments-in-sharepoint-2010-designer-approval-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: Thank You, this is what I needed. I had already done those steps however, I was trying to retrieve the value in the Task is Pending section and I never saw the value I wanted. Now that I am retrieving the value in the Task Complete and setting it to a variable I can use it where I need to for the remainder of the task being processed. I had understood the concept of the new task form fields and I had already viewed the information from the two links provided.